# How to read big csv file batch by batch in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, csv

I have a csv file which contains more than 500k records. Fields of the csv are

- name
- age
- branch

Without loading huge data in to memory I need to process all the records from the file. Need to read few records insert them in to collection and manipulate and then continue reading remaining records. As I'm new to this, unable to understand how it would work. If I try to print the batch, it prints buffered data, will the below code work for my requirement? With that buffered value, how can i get the csv record & insert, manipulate file data.

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath)
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data',(data) => {
            batch.push(data)
            counter ++;
            if(counter == 100){
                
                stream.pause()
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log("batch in ",data)
                    counter = 0;
                    batch = []
                    stream.resume()},5000)
            }
        })
        .on('error',(e) => {
             console.log("er ",e);
        })
        .on('end',() => {
             console.log("end");
        })
```

Comment: It is pretty hard to read a file via stream, replace some data and put it back to the same file. What is your exact use case? are you limited to using csv ? Maybe some sort of database would help out..

Comment: @SilvanBregy I need to read a huge CSV file and store the records in to a mongo db, and then manipulate the records.. Could you please help me out?

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not very clear. You have to point out in small terms what you want to achieve (I want to read a large csv file into a mongodatabase using streams), 

It also helps if you write your usecase: "I have a small application which reads in csv and stores it to mongodb. (maaybe. the people suggest you to use an alternative technique etc...

Generally all your written questions are quiet unclear why you don't get help easily.

Answer (score 0):

I have written you some sample code how to work with streams.
You basically create a stream and proceed with it's chunks. A chunk is an object of type `buffer`. To work on it as text call `toString()`.

Haven't a lot of time to explain you more but the comments should help out.

Also consider to use a module, since csv parsing was already done a lot.
Hope this helps>

```
import * as fs from 'fs'

// end oof line delimiter, system specific.
import { EOL } from 'os'

// the delimiter used in csv
var delimiter = ','

// add your own implementttaion of parsing a portion of  the text here.
const parseChunk = (text,  index) => {

    // first chunk, the header is included here. 
    if(index === 0) {
        // The first row will be the header. So take it
        var headerLine = text.substring(0, text.indexOf(EOL))
        
        // remove the header from the text for further processing.
        // also replace the  new line character..
        text = text.replace(headerLine+EOL, '')

        // Do something with header here..
        
    }


    // Now you have a part of the file to process without headers.
    // The csv parse function you need to figure out yourself. Best
    // is to use some module for that. there are plenty of edge cases
    // when parsing csv.

    // custom csv parser here =>h ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/example-javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data

    // if the csv is well formatted it could be enough to use  this
    var lines = text.split(EOL)
        
    for(var line of lines) {
        var values = line.split(delimiter)
        console.log('liine  received', values)
        // StoreToDb(values)
    }
}

// create the stream
const stream = fs.createReadStream('file.csv')

// variable to count the  chunks  for knowing if header is inckuded..
var chunkCount = 0

// handle data event of stream
stream.on('data', chunk => {


    // the stream sends you a Buffer
    // to have it as text, convert it to string
    const text = chunk.toString()

    // Note that chunks will be a fixed size
    // but mostly consist of multiple lines,
    parseChunk(text, chunkCount)

    // increment the count.
    chunkCount++
})

stream.on('end', () => {
    console.log('parsing finished')
})

stream.on('error', (err) => {
    // error, handle properly here, maybe rollback changess already made to db
    // and parse again. You can may also use the chunkCount to start the parsing
    // again and omit first x chunks, so u can restsart at given point
    console.log('parsing error ', err)
})
```